# ASP.net - Could Not Load Type Nname.name

Tags: asp.net, parsing

I am new to this programming language and I need help with this. Not very sure what is wrong. But it kept prompting the error below and it would not display the data from MySQL workbench database.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Nname.name'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="name.Master.cs" Inherits="Nname.name" %>
```

This is my form page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phContent" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
             <th>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Country Code
            </th>
            <th>
                Disctrict
            </th>
            <th>
                Population
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="large">
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ID" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="CountryCode" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="District" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Population" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

This is my database code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace P1
{
    public class records
    {
        MySqlConnection con = null; 
        MySqlCommand cmd = null; 
        MySqlDataReader rdr ; 
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet(cmd,con); //
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(); 

        public void read()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new MySqlConnection("Server=myServerName;Database=myDatabaseName;Uid=myID;Pwd=myPassword");

                con.Open();

                string cmd = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE ID=6;";

                //da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
            }
            catch()
            { }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your master page and change

```
Inherits="Nname.name"
```

to

```
Inherits="name.name"
```

or

```
Inherits="name.master"
```

Comment: What is the name space and class of the master page in codebehind? That is what you to enter in the inherits.

Comment: so the inherits would be the name of the namepsace. the name of the class?

Comment: That's correct. And be aware that some namespaces can be multi-part (i.e. system.runtime).

Comment: ok. thanks! but what about my web form page? for the inherit. is it the same as what i put for the master page?

Comment: It follows the same rules, but won't be the same as the master page: it is the namespace plus the page name. Basically, you are telling asp.net which class in the DLL to use and the class is the code generated for the page, user control, master page, etc.

Comment: what are you trying to say is that for my web form page, i will be using the name of the namespace. the page name of my web form?

Comment: I have changed the inherits accordingly however it still gives me parse error showing the same error again.